# Добавление даты в базу

Tags: phpmyadmin, база-данных, php, дата, mysql

Есть три переменные. Значения переменных - даты. 
Получаю переменные так:

```
$dpBirthDate_ddlDay = $_POST['dpBirthDate_ddlDay'];
$dpBirthDate_ddlMonth = $_POST['dpBirthDate_ddlMonth'];
$dpBirthDate_ddlYear = $_POST['dpBirthDate_ddlYear'];

$dpDateOfIssue_ddlDay = $_POST['dpDateOfIssue_ddlDay'];
$dpDateOfIssue_ddlMonth = $_POST['dpDateOfIssue_ddlMonth'];
$dpDateOfIssue_ddlYear = $_POST['dpDateOfIssue_ddlYear'];

$dpDateOfExpire_ddlDay = $_POST['dpDateOfExpire_ddlDay'];
$dpDateOfExpire_ddlYear = $_POST['dpDateOfExpire_ddlYear'];
$dpDateOfExpire_ddlMonth = $_POST['dpDateOfExpire_ddlMonth'];
$Birthdate = $dpBirthDate_ddlYear.'-'.$dpBirthDate_ddlMonth.'-'.$dpBirthDate_ddlDay;
$DateOfExpire = $dpDateOfExpire_ddlYear.'-'.$dpDateOfExpire_ddlMonth.'-'.$dpDateOfExpire_ddlDay;
$DateOfIssu = $dpDateOfIssue_ddlYear.'-'.$dpDateOfIssue_ddlMonth.'-'.$dpDateOfIssue_ddlDay;
```

После выполняется запрос в базу, который добавляет эти три даты и другие поля в таблицу.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabl_name (`userid`, `Prefix`, `first_Name`, `middle_name`, `last_name`, `place_of_birth`, `birth_date`, `citizenship`, `country_of_residence`, `document_number`, `place_of_lssue`, `lssue_date`, `expire_date`, `document_type`, `image_file`) 
VALUES  ('$userid','$ddlPrefix','$txtFirstName','$txtMiddleName','$txtLastName','$txtPlaceOfBirth','$Birthdate', '$ddlCitizenship' , '$ddlCountryOfResidence' , '$txtDocumentNumber','$txtPlaceOfIssue','$DateOfIssu',$DateOfExpire,'$ddlDocumentType', '$newFileName' ) " or die ("Ошибка при добавлении в базу!<br/>" . mysql_error());
```

И вот что происходит. 
В первые два столбца значения добавляются, а в третье нет. 
Причем можно переменные местами менять - эффект такой же. 
Структура столбцов идентична.
А именно - просто название и формат DATE (Столбцы expire_date  lssue_date birth_date)

При выводе всех переменных через echo все даты в порядке и выводятся в формате 2014-01-01.

Но вот такая штука - если я устанавливаю формат третьего столбца как текстовый - добавляется туда не дата, а сумма. Например 2014-01-01=2012. Вот 2012 и вписывается.
=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я уже писал: кавычки пропустили!
    ... ,'$DateOfIssu',**$DateOfExpire**,'$ddlDocumentType', ...

Comment: Вот я осел!=)